# Optimizing SQL- swapping out functions for JOINS and confusion when variables exist

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance-testing

I just started a new job in Dev Ops at a publishing company. My first task is to optimize a huge SQL query that is composed of functions. Functions are really slow. The guy that created the query was smart but didn't know SQL and used functions when he could have used JOINs instead. I am having trouble with converting the functions that have variables. For example, this is one of the functions. Here it is within the query and next is the associated function stored elsewhere.

```
dbo.rpt_get_isbn(b.bookkey, 21) AS 
f_upc
```

Then the function...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[rpt_get_isbn](
        @i_bookkey  INT,
        @i_isbn_type    INT)

/*  Returns the identifier such as EAN, 
ISBN, with or without dashes


   PARAMETER @i_isbn_type
        10 = ISBN10
        13 = ISBN 13
        16 = EAN
        17 = EAN (no dashes)
        18 = GTIN
        19 = GTIN (no dashes)
        20 = LCCN
        21 = UPC
*/
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @RETURN VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @v_desc VARCHAR(50)

    IF @i_isbn_type = 10
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = isbn10
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END

    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 13
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = isbn
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END

    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 16
        BEGIN
           SELECT @v_desc = ean
           FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END
    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 17
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = ean13
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END
    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 18
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = gtin
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END
    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 19
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = gtin14
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END
    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 20
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = lccn
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END
    ELSE IF @i_isbn_type = 21
        BEGIN
            SELECT @v_desc = upc
            FROM isbn
            WHERE bookkey = @i_bookkey
        END
    IF LEN(@v_desc) > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @RETURN = 
LTRIM(RTRIM(@v_desc))
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @RETURN = ''
        END

  RETURN @RETURN
END
```

So this function can return various different results based on the variable given as the second parameter.  If that wasn't there, this would be easy.  I would simply convert it with a solution like this one to retrieve the book's cover..

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(bo.ean13)) AS p_coverimagepath
```

and the JOIN needed...

```
LEFT JOIN Isbn bo WITH (NOLOCK) ON bo.bookkey = b.bookkey
```

But again, now I'm dealing with parameters and a function that uses If/elses to derive an answer.  So do I need to add this if/else logic to my main query?  I can't think of a ways that will yield as simple an answer.  I look forward to figuring this out.  Please let me know if I forgot any crucial elements to understand what I'm doing.  Thanks!

***UPDATE***
Here's where the code is going

```
,pss8.dbo.xml_StripIllegalChars(dbo.rpt_get_series_volume(b.bookkey)) AS 
p_seriesvol
    ,CASE
        WHEN dbo.rpt_get_isbn(b.bookkey, 17) = ''
            THEN (
                    SELECT ipg_id
                    FROM tmmdb.ipg_extra.dbo.vw_Pss8IsbnOrUpc bo
                    WHERE bo.bookkey = b.bookkey
                    )
        ELSE dbo.rpt_get_isbn(b.bookkey, 17)
        END AS p_coverimagepath
    ,CASE
        WHEN dbo.rpt_get_isbn(b.bookkey, 17) = ''
            THEN (
                    SELECT ipg_id
                    FROM tmmdb.ipg_extra.dbo.vw_Pss8IsbnOrUpc bo
                    WHERE bo.bookkey = b.bookkey
                    )
        ELSE dbo.rpt_get_isbn(b.bookkey, 17)
        END AS TSP_p_coverimagepath
    ,pss8.dbo.xml_StripIllegalChars(replace(dbo.rpt_get_title(b.bookkey, 
'T'), '&', '&amp;')) AS p_title /*  30OCT14 */
    
,pss8.dbo.xml_StripIllegalChars(replace(dbo.rpt_get_sub_title(b.bookkey), 
'&', '&amp;')) AS p_subtitle /* 20OCT14 */
```

Comment: It's kind'a hard to tell without seeing the actual code that uses the function. Also, are all these columns `VARCHAR(50)`?

Comment: Why should you use that function? If that is an obligatory (why) then you can at least optimize a bit using a With .. (select ...) struct. And, why would you think a function using if else struct is slow? Looking at the code, the real slow part is the SQL using that function.

Comment: I don't follow.  Imagine trying to explain that to someone 2 weeks into learning SQL.  Not trying to bash your answer.. just further explain my situation.  This is what I see.  I see in the larger, main portion that there is a function.  I see its within a CASE.  This function also has conditional logic within it.  So if I try to imagine taking that logic out of the function. I assume it has to go into the main query in some fashion.  Please base answers off these assumptions.  ex-- "if that is obligatory...' I have no idea if anything is obligatory.

Comment: Or can anyone just answer this--- I have a function
`dbo.rpt_get_isbn(b.bookkey, 17)`

The 17 is a variable.  How do I use JOINS instead when dealing with a dynamic variable

Comment: It depends how the parameter value is fed in - is it a column in a table? You are 100% right that this shouldn't have been written this way.

Comment: A quick look at the function seems to indicate it's just picking a different column depending on the input. Which is possibly a data modelling issue, but hard to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but an example structure to help you dig your way out of this. I have made many assumptions because your question requires more detail. But hopefully you can appreciate this is way simpler.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(bo.ean13)),'') = '' THEN T2.ipg_id 
    ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(bo.ean13))
END as p_coverimagepath
FROM MainTable b
LEFT JOIN Isbn bo 
ON bo.bookkey = b.bookkey
LEFT JOIN tmmdb.ipg_extra.dbo.vw_Pss8IsbnOrUpc T2
ON T2.bookkey=b.bookkey
```

In your example code, two columns do exactly the same thing so I haven't repeated this.

A few things noted:

-Don't sprinkle `NOLOCK` in your code thinking it's a performance boost

-If you're using an outer join, you need to accommodate in case a NULL is returned

-It's easier to join once to `tmmdb.ipg_extra.dbo.vw_Pss8IsbnOrUpc` and use columns out of it rather than repeat the code over and over.